# CONNECT requests are not supported

Tags: java, ssl, proxy, playframework

I am writing an HTTPS proxy in play framework, yet every time I try to run it on a website that has ssl encryption I am getting this error in my server:

> akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(play-dev-mode) Illegal request, responding with status '400 Bad Request': CONNECT requests are not suppo
> rted: Rejecting CONNECT request to '//any.website:443'

The proxy works well on HTTP, yet HTTPS is the problem. I tried changing my application.conf to have a port destined to work on HTTPS, but when I try to run it with the keystore i setup using the keytool command I am getting the following error in my browser:

> Secure Connection Failed

> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
> Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

Any workaround to allow HTTPS on a play framework proxy server?

Comment: *"I am writing an HTTPS proxy in play framework"* - and you are likely doing it wrong. Do you actually expect us to guess what you are doing (i.e. your code) from the error description in order to point out what you do wrong? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the problem is not code related - I set up using the proxy using the windows proxy settings (set up to use localhost:9104 - the port that i am running my proxy on), and it doesn't really matter what i am writing on my code - every website that I try to go to is getting the error that i mentioned, so I thought that maybe this is a known play problem

Comment: Then the proxy you use simply does not support to proxy HTTPS. Use a different proxy.